# I need to understand how to give deposit and withdraw permission to an aragonOSx plugin

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, dao, permissions

I'm currently looking at the `DAO.sol` contract and I cannot find:

- the specific permission I need for the `deposit` function (so that I can deposit assets into the DAO).
- any `withdraw` function so that I can withdraw assets from the DAO.

Using the new aragonOSx protocol, how would I go about doing such things?

Answer (score 0):

### Deposit

In regards to `deposit`, anyone can deposit assets into a DAO. You don't need any specific `permission` to do that.

### Withdraw

Withdrawing of course is riskier, so permissions are needed.

The way you would withdraw is actually calling on the `execute` function from the `DAO.sol` contract. So in order to call it, the address needs the `EXECUTE` permission.

You would then call something like this:

```
_dao.execute(
   bytes32(_proposalId),
   _actions,
   _allowFailureMap
);
```

- If you want to simply transfer ETH, you would add an `action` like `{ to: recipientAddress, value: ethAmount, data: null }`
- If you want to transfer an ERC20, you would add an `action` like `{ to: tokenContractAddress, value: 0, data: "<encoded-transfer(to, value)>"}`
- If you want to send an NFT, same as above.
- If you want to swap Uniswap tokens, you would encode `{ to: uniswapPoolAddr, value: 0, data: "<encoded-swap(...)>" }`

All of these actions you can encode and decode using the aragonOSx SDK (https://github.com/aragon/sdk).

#### Withdraw Examples

Here's an example of how to set it when you want to transfer funds upon a **proposal approval:**

```
proposal.actions = [
   { to: recipient, value },   // ETH
   { to: daiContract, value: 0, data: abiEncode(transfer, ...) },  // ERC20
   // ...
];
```

Here's an example of how it can be set up **within a plugin:** [image: code snippet]
*(Thank you @AbuUsama for the code snippet!)*